# I want all users which are not members of my User table to see everyones data

Tags: ssas, tabular, ssas-tabular, row-level-security

I have a table with Sales Teams (DimSalgsTeams) and another one with all salelsmen for all teams (DimSaelgere), and only a users (salesmen) from the same Team can see each others rows.
My model works great, but the issue is that all other members of specified AD Group should see everything.
How can I achive that in this model?

[image: ssas model]

[image: relationship between Users and UserTeams]

[image: role manager]

[image: row filter]

Comment: I'm not sure I understood, but if you create a new role with no filters and add the AD group in to that role, then those people can see everything?

Comment: That will solve my problem, but it's not an option. We want all users in the same AD group. But I have found a solution.I changed the code in DAX filter to:

=IF(CONTAINS(DimBrugerRettigheder, [original_login], USERNAME()), DimBrugerRettigheder[original_login] = USERNAME(), TRUE())

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code in DAX filter to:
=IF(CONTAINS(DimBrugerRettigheder, [original_login], USERNAME()), DimBrugerRettigheder[original_login] = USERNAME(), TRUE())

And it solved my problem.